# Applying XSLT in .NET different (incorrect) result vs. Notepad++

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, transform, scope

I have an XML file, in which an attribute on the parent element drives logic for transformation of child elements.

When I apply this XSLT transform in Notepad++'s XML Tools plugin, I get correct and expected result. However when I use `XslCompiledTransform` the result comes out as if it's missing the declared variable. I tried debugging XSLT in Visual Studio and the variable's value is always `NULL`.

What am I doing incorrectly in .NET?

XML:

```
 <summary>
   <section format="2" title="ACCOUNT SUMMARY">
        <section_box>
          <subTotal>
            <description>BALANCE FORWARD</description>
            <amount />
          </subTotal>
          <line>
            <description>Previous Balance</description>
            <amount>$155.64</amount>
          </line>
          <line>
            <description>Payments Received</description>
            <amount>$155.64 CR</amount>
          </line>
          <subTotal>
            <description>TOTAL BALANCE FORWARD</description>
            <amount>$0.00</amount>
          </subTotal>
        </section_box>
   </section>
   <section format="3" title="ACCOUNT DETAILS">
        <section_box>
          <line>        <label>Charge</label>
            <description>Monthly Charge for Service</description>
            <amount>$155.64</amount>
          </line>
          <subTotal>
            <description>TOTAL NEW BALANCE</description>
            <amount>$155.64</amount>
          </subTotal>
        </section_box>
   </section>
 </summary>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="summary">
        <summary>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="section" />
        </summary>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="section">
        <xsl:variable name="row-format" select="@format" />
        <xsl:if test="@title">
            <title>
                <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
            </title>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="line|subTotal|section_box">
            <xsl:with-param name="row-format" select="$row-format" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="line">
        <xsl:param name="row-format" />
        <line>
            <xsl:attribute name="format">
                <xsl:value-of select="$row-format"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:if test="$row-format = '2'">
                <description>
                    <xsl:value-of select="description" />
                </description>
                <date>
                    <xsl:value-of select="date" />
                </date>
                <amount>
                    <xsl:value-of select="amount" />
                </amount>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$row-format = '3'">
                <label>
                    <xsl:value-of select="label" />
                </label>
                <description>
                    <xsl:value-of select="description" />
                </description>
                <amount>
                    <xsl:value-of select="amount" />
                </amount>
            </xsl:if>
        </line>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="subtotal|subTotal">
        <xsl:param name="row-format" />
        <subtotal>
            <description>
                <xsl:value-of select="description" />
            </description>
            <amount>
                <xsl:value-of select="amount" />
            </amount>
        </subtotal>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Result (and from Notepad++, note `line` elements contents and `format` attribute is correct):

```
<summary>
    <title>ACCOUNT SUMMARY</title>
    <subtotal>
        <description>BALANCE FORWARD</description>
        <amount/>
    </subtotal>
    <line format="2">
        <description>Previous Balance</description>
        <date/>
        <amount>$155.64</amount>
    </line>
    <line format="2">
        <description>Payments Received</description>
        <date/>
        <amount>$155.64 CR</amount>
    </line>
    <subtotal>
        <description>TOTAL BALANCE FORWARD</description>
        <amount>$0.00</amount>
    </subtotal>
    <title>ACCOUNT DETAILS</title>
    <line format="3">
        <label>Charge</label>
        <description>Monthly Charge for Service</description>
        <amount>$155.64</amount>
    </line>
    <subtotal>
        <description>TOTAL NEW BALANCE</description>
        <amount>$155.64</amount>
    </subtotal>
</summary>
```

.NET Produces (note missing content of `line`s because no matching `format` is found; because it's `NULL`):

```
<summary>
    <title>ACCOUNT SUMMARY</title>
    <subtotal>
        <description>BALANCE FORWARD</description>
        <amount/>
    </subtotal>
    <line format="" />
    <line format="" />
    <subtotal>
        <description>TOTAL BALANCE FORWARD</description>
        <amount>$0.00</amount>
    </subtotal>
    <title>ACCOUNT DETAILS</title>
    <line format="" />
    <subtotal>
        <description>TOTAL NEW BALANCE</description>
        <amount>$155.64</amount>
    </subtotal>
</summary>
```

.NET code executed:

```
Dim compiled As New XslCompiledTransform(True)
compiled.Load("C:\summary.xsl")
compiled.Transform("C:\Summary.xml", "C:\TransformedSummary.xml")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="line|subTotal|section_box">
        <xsl:with-param name="row-format" select="$row-format" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
```

to

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::line|descendant::subTotal">
        <xsl:with-param name="row-format" select="$row-format" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
```

or you would need to add a template

```
<xsl:template match="section_box">
  <xsl:param name="row-format"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
    <xsl:with-param name="row-format" select="$row-format"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

and then you would simply use

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="section_box">
        <xsl:with-param name="row-format" select="$row-format" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
```

With XSLT 1.0, parameters are not tunneled through automatically so I think the result you currently get for your code is correct, you are trying to apply templates to a `line` child element which does not exist so there nothing happens, then you apply templates to a `section_box` and pass the parameter, but as you have not written any template for that element the default template kicks in which does not pass the parameter when processing child nodes. So when your template for `line` is applied it does not get the parameter passed.

Comment: Thank you, the solution to prefix elements which rely on variable with "descendant::" solved the issue. Is there a way to "force" .NET3.5 to use XSLT 2.0? Or everything in .NET is done under XSLT 1.0 spec?
Would Notepad++ use XSLT 2.0 and so it worked or is there something else going on?

Comment: If you want to use XSLT 2.0 with .NET then you need to use a third party implementation like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime. XslCompiledTransform is an XSLT 1.0 processor. As for Notepad++, according to the plugin documentation, it uses libxml which is also an XSLT 1.0 processor. I am not sure why your code tunnels the parameter with Notepad++, if it uses an XSLT 1.0 processor then I would consider the behaviour a bug.